# Menu responsivo com grid layout

Tags: css, menu, layout, grid, layout-responsivo

Eu to aprendendo grid e layout responsivo e não sei a melhor maneira que
eu conseguiria criar um "hamburger menu" com ele.

Até agora eu consegui fazer meu wrapper de conteúdo se mover pra esquerda e deixar um espaço pro menu, mas não sei como colocar o menu no espaço que sobrou
ta aqui o link do exercicio:

https://jsfiddle.net/5kq8pas0/

Conseguem ajudar?

Comment: Aqui no https://pt.stackoverflow.com vc pode comentar em português...

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ô, fi, traduz a pergunta aí, mano. Tu tá no site português do Stackoverflow.

Comment: Editado senhores

Answer (score 1):

Você pode posicionar o menu adicionando um `position: relative;` e `top: 70px` dentro do `@media screen` na `ul` do menu (o valor `70px` você pode ajustar até que o menu fique no local desejado à partir do topo):

```
.multi-header ul{
   display: none;
   position: relative;
   top: 70px;
}
```

E também dentro do `@media screen`, adicionar o estilo abaixo para converter as `<li>` para `block`, de modo que uma fique abaixo da outra no menu:

```
.multi-header li{
    display: block;
}
```

**Veja funcionando** (desativei o `display: none` do menu para visualização):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleSidebar() {
        console.log("ayy");
       $(".button").toggleClass("active");
       $(".wrapper").toggleClass("move-to-left");
    //   $("main").toggleClass("move-to-left");
    //   $(".sidebar-item").toggleClass("active");
       $(".multi-header ul").toggleClass("menuativo menunaoativo");
    }
    
    $(".button").on("click tap", function() {
       toggleSidebar();
    });
    
    // $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    //   if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    //     toggleSidebar();
    //   }
    // });
});
```

```css
html, body{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color:#8f8f8f;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

nav{
 padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px,auto);
    -webkit-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

h1{
 color:#4c2779;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* MENU */
.multi-logo{
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.multi-header{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

.multi-header ul{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

.multi-header li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}


.multi-header li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* MENU ANIMATION */
.multi-header li a:hover{
    color: #4B2779;
    /* opacity: 0.5; */
}

.multi-header li a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #4B2779;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

.multi-header li a:hover:before{
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

     .menuativo{
         display: block;
     }

     .menunaoativo{
         display: none !important;
     }

/* MENU ANIMATION */
/* MENU */

/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
   .multi-header ul{
      display: block !important;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px), screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape), screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait){

.multi-header li{
    display: block;
}


    .multi-header nav{
        height: 30px;
    }

    .multi-header ul{
       position: relative;
       top: 70px;
     }
     
    .multi-menu-mobile{
        display: block;
    }

    .bar {
        -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
        -o-transition: all .7s ease;
        transition: all .7s ease;
      }
    
      .bar {
        display: block;
        height: 5px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: #4B2779;
        margin: 10px auto;
      }

      .button {
          float: right;
          cursor: pointer;
      }


      .button.active .top {
    
        -webkit-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
        -moz-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
        -o-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
        transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
      }
      
      .button.active .bottom {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
        -o-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
        transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
      }
      
      .button.active .middle {
        width: 0;
      }


      .move-to-left {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-250px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-250px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-250px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-250px);
        transform: translateX(-250px);
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="multi-header">
    <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/173777662/620757677/stock-vector-slide-penguin-logo-template-620757677.jpg" class="multi-logo">
    <nav>
     <div class="button" id="btn">
      <div class="bar top"></div>
      <div class="bar middle"></div>
      <div class="bar bottom"></div>
     </div>
     <ul class="menunaoativo">
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Solutions</a></li>
      <li><a>Cases</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
 <div class="wrapper">
  

  <section>
   <a name="slideShow"></a>

   <h1>Banner</h1>
  </section>
  
  <section>
   <a name="sec1"></a>

   <h1>Section 1</h1>
  </section>

  <section>
   <a name="sec2"></a>

   <h1>Section 2</h1>
  </section>
  
  <section>
   <a name="sec3"></a>
   <h1>Section 3</h1>
  </section>

  <footer>
   <h1>Footer</h1>''
  </footer>

 </div>
```

Comment: Hmm entendi, eu tava pensando que teria que usar o z-index do grid e fazer ele aparecer com ele

Comment: mas dai eu preciso de uma classe com display: none pra fazer o toggleClass se eu quiser sumir e aparecer com ele?

Comment: @ViniciusSouza Criei duas class no CSS: `.menuativo` e `.menunaoativo` e coloquei `.menunaoativo` na `ul`... e adicionei no jQuery `$(".multi-header ul").toggleClass("menuativo menunaoativo");`

Comment: @ViniciusSouza Adicionei tb outro `@media screen and (min-width: 768px){` para que o menu apareça quando o hamburguer sumir.